# What are the parent classes of `Console.Out` and `Console.In`?

Tags: c#

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.out(v=vs.110).aspx says that `Console.Out` has type `TextWriter`. Similarly https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.in(v=vs.110).aspx says that `Console.In` has type `TextReader`.

However, [`TextWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`TextReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader(v=vs.110).aspx) are both abstract classes. So they can't have instances directly.

What are the parent classes of `Console.Out` and `Console.In`?

Are they concrete classes?

Are they derived classes of `TextWriter` and `TextReader`?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `System.Out` and `System.In`? Do you mean `Console.Out` and `Console.In`? Those are just properties with types of `TextWriter` and `TextReader` respectively. The *value* of those properties at any time would either be null or a reference to an instance of a concrete class. It's not really clear what you mean when you ask about "parent classes".

Comment: @Jon: I have updated `System` to `Console`. What concrete classes are the types of the properties `Out` and `In` of `Console`?

Comment: @Hans: What are the default Concrete class types of `In` and `Out`?

Comment: What is `System.Out` you speak of? I cannot find it.

Comment: The default will be implementation-specific, but you can specify your own... for example `Console.SetOut(new StringWriter())`. Are you interested in these specific properties, or are you more generally asking how a property's type can be an abstract type.

Comment: @Jon both are interesting.

Comment: The source is [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,900c4f44633d4d99). If you dig far enough, you'll find things being initialized to `StreamWriter` and `StreamReader`, respectively, if you don't take action to set the properties differently.

Comment: "both are interesting" - maybe, but that's not an appropriate single Stack Overflow question. You should rewrite this question to *either* only ask about the concrete classes used by `Console.Out` and `Console.In` by default (which you could find out easily enough in any particular implementation by calling `Console.Out.GetType()` etc) *or* you should ask how a property type can be abstract or an interface.

Answer (score 1):

> What are the parent classes of Console.Out and Console.In?

These are properties, not types. They are meant to retrieve the `TextWriter` / `TextReader` instances that are currently used for input / output.

You can set these instances using `SetIn` and `SetOut`. Obviously, you need for that an instance of a concrete class, such as `StreamReader`

Comment: You are quoting someone but the OP never said that so who are you quoting?

Answer (score 1):

Simply run a program and ask for the runtime type of both:

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(Console.In.GetType().Name);
     Console.WriteLine(Console.Out.GetType().Name);
 }
```

Whatever prints out, those are the types you are looking for. I can't check right now, but they are probably `internal` (or even private nested) classes that derive the abstract types you mention.

Answer (score 1):

According to sourceof.net `Console.Out` is a simple `StreamWriter`

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/console.cs.html#372

Line 372.

And `Console.In` is a `StreamReader`.